# pdf for non-central gamma distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-function

I have a given gamma distribution as:
$f(x;k,\theta) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)\theta^{k}}x^{k-1}e^{\frac{-x}{\theta}}$ and a non-centrality parameter $\delta$.
Now, I need to find the pdf of this non-central gamma distribution $f(x;k,\theta,\delta)$?

I have found an expression of this in a paper by Oliveira and Ferreira. However, the pdf expression is in terms of shape parameter and non-centrality parameter only, which is given as
$f(x;k,\delta) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-\delta}{2}}\left(\frac{\delta}{2}\right)^i \left[ \frac{1}{\Gamma(k+i)}e^{-x}x^{k+i-1}\right]$.

Is there an expression for pdf that incorporates x,$\theta$,k, and $\delta$? Or, any approximations to make the non-central distribution to the central distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y = g(x)$ be a 1 to 1 transformation, so $x = g^{-1}(y)$

In your case $Y = \frac{1}{X+\delta}$, so $X = \frac{1}{Y}-\delta=g^{-1}(Y)$

$f_Y(y) = |\frac{d}{dy}(g^{-1}(y))|f_X(g^{-1}(y))$

Why is this the case? $f_X(g^{-1}(y))$ is just $f_X(x)$ with $y$ plugged in, $|\frac{d}{dy}(g^{-1}(y))|$ is the change of variable term - same as doing a substitution in an integral

For your example, we get

$|\frac{d}{dy}(\frac{1}{y}-\delta)| = \frac{1}{y^2}$

$\dfrac{(\frac{1}{y}-\delta)^{k-1} e^{-\frac{1}{\theta}(\frac{1}{y}-\delta)}}{\theta^k \Gamma (k)} \times \frac{1}{y^2} = \dfrac{(\frac{1}{y}-\delta)^{k-1} e^{-\frac{1}{\theta}(\frac{1}{y}-\delta)}}{y^2\theta^k \Gamma (k)} $

so $f_Y(y) = \dfrac{(\frac{1}{y}-\delta)^{k-1} e^{-\frac{1}{\theta}(\frac{1}{y}-\delta)}}{y^2\theta^k \Gamma (k)}$ for $y<\frac{1}{\delta}$

Now your job:

make sure you understand this and try to do it for normal distribution.

Comment: thanks. was of great help. and could the mean and variance be generalized too? :)

Comment: @Sam please be more specific. if you mean, can we calculate the mean of this thing. I believe the answer is no. for $\delta = 0$, this is known. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution but $1/(y+\delta)$ is pretty nasty, so i do not think so.

Comment: I could actually get to this,
I know $X$ is gamma distributed so its easy for mean(X) and var(X).

Now $(X+\delta)$ has mean=mean(X)+$\delta$ and variance = var(X).

So, I am looking for an alternative to calculate the mean of $\dfrac{1}{X+\delta}$. I agree it might get too nasty.

Comment: @Sam yes, unfortunately $E(1/(X+\delta))$ is almost never a nice object.

Comment: @Sam I know this post is quite old but the $E((X+\delta)^{-1})=\frac{e^{-\delta/\theta}}{\theta}E_k(-\delta/\theta)$ for $\delta>0$. $E_\nu(z)$ is the generalized exponential integral function.

Comment: @Sam $E((X+\delta)^{-1})=\frac{1}{\theta(k-1)}$ for $\delta=0$.  Lookup the "inverse gamma distribution".

Comment: @Sam For $\delta<0$ the mean of this distribution can be defined according to the Cauchy principal value and is equal to $\operatorname{p.v.}E((X+\delta)^{-1})=\frac{e^{-\delta/\theta}}{\theta}\Re\{E_k(-\delta/\theta)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my monte-carlo simulation and closed form expression match, the non-central gamma could be well approximated by Amoroso distribution i.e.,
$f(x;k,\theta,\delta) = \frac{1}{\theta^k\Gamma(\theta)}(x-\delta)^{k-1}e^{\left(\frac{-(x-\delta)}{\theta} \right)}$
where $\delta$ is the location parameter.

Comment: What is non central gamma? If you just want to shift the distribution to the right by delta. I.e. Do $\delta+X$ where $X$ is a gamma distribution. This is pretty clear via change of variable.

Comment: Well I was talking about the distribution when the gamma distribution is shifted by some known parameters.

Comment: Yeah so $X+\delta$ where $X$ is a standard gamma, this answer is correct. Have you rad my answer to your other question.

Comment: so, you mean say $X$ is gamma distributed with pdf $f_{X}(x)$ and $X+\delta$ has some distribution with pdf $\delta+f_{X}(x)$ or $f_{X}(x+\delta)$. and neither is true.

Comment: Nope, i am or saying that. I am saying $X+\delta$ has pdf $f_X(x-\delta)$, isn't this obvious from your answer? This is via a change of variable argument, rather than all this simulation you did, which is not a proof. This is actually for any distribution with a density function/mass function.

Comment: Yes, i see now. The term you provided and Amoroso matches :) 
Thanks

Comment: @Lost1 Is there also an straight forward argument about the distribution $\dfrac{1}{X+\delta}$, considering $X$ to be gamma distributed?

Comment: Then what would be the density function for $\dfrac{1}{X+\delta}$, considering $X$ to be gamma distributed

Comment: Yes, that was obvious too. And Amoroso could be generalized to Gamma or Generalized Gamma too. The fact it already has the 'location parameter' makes it quite easy to have an intuition regarding the pdf. And ofcourse the inverse of a function is trivial.

Comment: This is the best answer for practical work. I made a variational model out of this that works great.